# "Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two CFIndex operands" - choosing a phone number from ABMultiValue (Address Book)

Tags: ios, swift, addressbook, addressbookui, abmultivalue

I'm trying to use AddressBook and AddressBookUI to show a view of the address book, where a user can then tap on a contact and then the phone number, and the app receives the phone number. I'm having an issue when I iterate through the ABMultiValue looking to find the entry with the selected identifier - the error "`Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two CFIndex operands`" is raised on the line with the `for` loop (line 13).

I've pasted the code below - does anyone have any idea why this happening / what I can do to fix it?  Thanks!

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) {
    self.peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker, shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson: person, property: property, identifier: identifier)

    // Get name
    //    If wanting a composite name including prefix, suxif, title, both names etc:
    //    NSString *contactName = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person));
    let contactName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)

    // Get number
    var number = String()
    let numbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty)

    for var index:CFIndex = 0; index < ABMultiValueGetCount(numbers); ++index{
        if identifier = ABMultiValueGetIdentifierAtIndex(numbers, index) {
            number = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers, index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to turn the CFIndex values into numbers.

Comment: @matt how do I do that? I tried assigning straight to a var:Int, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cycle using normal numbers:

```
for index in 0 ..< ABMultiValueGetCount(numbers) {
```

Comment: I get back to a different error on conversion:  "'(IntegerLiteralConvertible, CFIndex)' is not convertible to 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'"

Comment: You forgot to take the retained value of `numbers`.

Comment: See my example here https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch18p713addressBook/ch31p973addressBook/ViewController.swift

Comment: that explained it perfectly - thank you :) I didn't realise about using takeRetainedValue()